# Почему атрибут data на HTML 5 возвращает значение undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При получении значения атрибута `data` возникает возникает ошибка из-за значения `undefined`.

На этом участке кода значение атрибута `data` верное: `url: '/moderator/comment/' + $( this ).data( 'id' ) + '/delete',` а здесь и далее уже `undefined`: `alert( "#comment" + $( this ).data( 'id' ) );`

```js
$("[id^=comment_delete]").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/moderator/comment/' + $(this).data('id') + '/delete',

    success: function(msg) {
      alert("#comment" + $(this).data('id'));
      $("#comment" + $(this).data('id')).detach();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#comment_delete {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comment100500" class="panel panel-default" data-id="100500">
  <div id="comment_delete100500" data-id="100500" class="btn btn-danger" data-href="/moderator/comment/100500/delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Delete</div>
  <p>Комментарий</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы запустите сниппет ниже, то в консоли увидите, что вы пытаетесь получить данные у объекта, на который ссылается `this`, в то время как объектом является не `div`, а функция `ajax`-запроса, так как именно она в этот момент является тем, на что должен ссылаться this в этой области видимости.

Чтобы же получить нужную вам информацию, вам нужно (можно) прибегнуть к тому способу, как я привел там же, а именно сохранить ссылку на нужный вам `div` в переменной `btn`, и потом использовать именно ее. Ну или еще как-то обращаться именно к этому объекту, а не к иному.

```js
$("[id^=comment_delete]").on("click", function() {
  var btn = this;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/moderator/comment/' + $(this).data('id') + '/delete',

    complete: function(msg) {
      console.log(this);
      alert("#comment" + $(btn).data('id'));
      $("#comment" + $(this).data('id')).detach();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#comment_delete {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comment100500" class="panel panel-default" data-id="100500">
  <div id="comment_delete100500" data-id="100500" class="btn btn-danger" data-href="/moderator/comment/100500/delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Delete</div>
  <p>Комментарий</p>
</div>
```